# Rails 3 app boot problems on development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have Rails 3 app on server.

It works just fine, but pretty often fails to boot. 
I have tried to run `tmp/restart.txt` to restart Phusion Passanger server, but there is no change at all. It can be even half-hour to finally get access to my app.

I reviewed my log files, but there is no sign off any errors ore something other that could cause such major delay.

I tried to test my app using New Relic but even there was no succes to actually connect my site, with no errors at all.

Comment: You realise that you didn't give any meaningful details about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `passenger-config restart-app` to force Phuson Passenger to restart your app.

Comment: After this I get *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.